# Rails 3 Edit Multiple Records in a Single Form

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-3, editing, railscasts

I've been stuck on this problem for a couple of days now.

I've have some success with Railscasts Episode #198, but that one is for Rails 2. There have been some changes in Rails 3 that make it so the code provided in Episode #198 won't work.

The problem lies within the edit_individual.html.erb:

Original Code (provided by Ryan @ Railscasts):

```
<% form_tag update_individual_products_path, :method => :put do %>
  <% for product in @products %>
    <% fields_for "products[]", product do |f| %>
      <h2><%=h product.name %></h2>
      <%= render "fields", :f => f %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= submit_tag "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Modified Code (simply changed fields_for to form_for):

```
<% form_tag update_individual_products_path, :method => :put do %>
  <% for product in @products %>
    <% form_for "products[]", product do |f| %>
      <h2><%=h product.name %></h2>
      <%= render "fields", :f => f %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= submit_tag "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

In the new code, each record is placed within a form of their own, all inside one single form (which is the one I only want).

My question is, how can I get the code provided by Railscasts Episode #198 to work in Rails 3?

Here is a link to the Railscast I mentioned:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/198-edit-multiple-individually

Thank You,
c.allen.rosario

Comment: You cannot use `form_for` inside another `form_for` because that would mean a `<form>` tag inside another `<form>` tag. You **do** need to use `fields_for`. What are the errors when you run the code in Rails 3 ?

Comment: No errors are displayed. I just get a blank page with a submit button.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found the solution. Just need to modify the following line in the code provided by Ryan @ Railscasts:

```
<% fields_for "products[]", product do |f| %>
```

and change it to:

```
<%= fields_for "products[]", product do |f| %>
```

Notice, that the `<%` has been modified to `<%=`.

final solution:

```
<% form_tag update_individual_products_path :method => :put do %>  
  <% for product in @products %>  
    <%= fields_for "products[]", product do |f| %>  
      <h2><%= h product.name %></h2>  
    <% end %>  
  <% end %>  
  <p><%= submit_tag "Submit" %></p>  
<% end %>
```

I was wondering if anyone could explain this solution to me. From what I understand you should only need a `<%` in front of the `fields_for`.

c.allen.rosario

Comment: Yes, that `=` is required in Rails 3, though it was not required in earlier Rails versions. Did you not need to use it for the `form_tag` ?

Comment: The = was not required for the form_tag

Comment: I think a comma is missing, your final solution should start with: `<% form_tag update_individual_products_path, :method => :put do %>`

Comment: For clarification: <%= is used if you expect some output to be written to the DOM (like a form tag, or an input field etc) whereas <% is used for situations where no output is expected (e.g. logic like <% if %>...<% end %>). This is the standard since rails 3

Answer (score 4):

The change in Rails 3 from <% fields_for to <%= fields_for is because it was confusing that form_for, form_tag, etc... were using <% form... %> **even though** they they were outputting html code.
With Rails 3, since they output html code, they use <%=.

Please note that your first line is deprecated:

```
<% form_tag update_individual_products_path, :method => :put do %>
```

should be

```
<%= form_tag update_individual_products_path, :method => :put do %>
```

Same for all form tags.