# Editing multiple records in one form - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, forms, controller, nested-forms

I'm trying to edit multiple records using one form, so the user can edit a few records then press submit at the end rather than after each individual one. I've posted my current code, and I get this error:

```
undefined method `connection_connection_path'
```

Controller

```
def show
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
  @connection = @customer.connections
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @customer }
  end
end
```

View

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <th>Interface</th>
        <th>Device</th>
        <th>Speed</th>
        <th>Site</th>
        <th>Capable</th>
        <th>Notes</th>

    </thead>
    <%= form_for(@connection) do |f| %>
    <% @connection.each do |l| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= l.interface %></td>
        <td><%= l.device %></td>
        <td><%= l.speed %></td>
        <td><%= l.site.name%> </td>
        <td><%= f.check_box :check %></td>
        <td><%= f.text_field :notes %></td>

    </tr>
    <% end %>
            <tr><%= f.submit %></tr>
</table>
<% end %>
```

routes

```
resources :connections


resources :sites


resources :customer_sites


resources :customers

root :to => "customers#index"
```

Comment: Can you update to include your routes.rb?

Comment: This is not one form, but multiple forms. If you want to have a single submit button for all the forms - then perhaps you need some javascript - on "click"in the final submit button -> then indivdually "submit" the changes on all the relevant "mini-forms" which are contained in the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so where is your submit button?? and it should not done in show, maybe you might create a new method in your controller and do the multiple edit function.

The basic concept is when you have checks, you need to pass an array of your object to your method, and update them one by one. or you can do that using JS as well.

refer this railscast
http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple

and this stackoverflow
[Rails 3 Edit Multiple Records in a Single Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383391/rails-3-edit-multiple-records-in-a-single-form)

these resources you can get easily by google :D
if still have problem, just come and ask here again

Comment: I've updated my question with a submit button, I don't understand how to do a multiple edit function.. that's part of my question!

Comment: Thanks, I think I've got a bit further with the stackoverflow answer.. I'll see if I can get it to work!